# JScroll - add content scrolling to top?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very long list of options to load as list items.  I am using jScroll to load the first 500 items and to add more 500 at a time.  There are over 30,000 items in my list.

If some (crazed) user gets past say 3,000 list items in the scroll, things start to bog down - perhaps based on the size of the page.  After a maximum number of "displayable" items, we want to start chopping things off the top -- removing list items, but we want to be able to put them back by scrolling up.

I can make the "chop off" part happen by creating a function and using the callback option.

Can jScroll work in reverse (hit the top of the scroll and add content)?

Comment: It may be more practical to allow users to search for the relevant items rather than an unweildy list.

Comment: i couldn't agree more, but i'm trying to comply with the request of the business owner.

Comment: I don't know how jScroll works, but recently I had a table with 5 columns about 10000 rows. Loaded that with jQuery DataTables (datatables.net) and had no performance problems which you're describing. I would have a look at it if I were you. It also has a server-side function and a built-in advanced search option.

Comment: and we do have a nice search feature ... this functionality is just in case someone wants to scroll all the way through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would just detecting a scroll through jquery work for you? Something like . . .

```js
var $container = $('.scrollable');

$container.scroll(function () {
  if ($container.scrollTop() == 0) {
    alert('Scrolled to Top');

  }
});
```

```css
.scrollable {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollable">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>16</li>
    <li>17</li>
    <li>18</li>
    <li>19</li>
    <li>20</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I went with ... The jscroll thing kept getting in my way because it didn't expect for the number of elements to be in flux as it calculated where to land.

Comment: Nice, glad it was helpful.